# Limit of a seuence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose that $ a_{n,m}\in {\Bbb R}^+$ for $(n,m\in {\Bbb N})$ such that $a_{n,m}\to a_m$ when $n\to \infty$, and also $\sum_m a_{n,m}$ is convergent. Could conclude that $$\sum_m a_m =\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_m a_{n,m}$$

Answer (score 0):

No, let $a_{i,j}$ be $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @GuyFsone it doesn't?